# Scala - Find whether all Futures of a Sequence passed or not

Tags: scala, future, flatmap

I have a function `f` which returns a `Future[Unit]`. I want to apply the function `f` onto a sequence of Strings, such that I get a `Seq[Future[Unit]]`.

To convert it into a single Future, we are using `Future.sequence` which converts it into a `Future[Seq[Unit]]`. Now, since the function `f` can either fail or pass, we also convert it into a `Try` (to better handle the failures) using `FutureUtil.toTry` which gives us a `Future[Try[Seq[Unit]]]`.

Now, the deal is that we don't want to know which Futures passed or not, but the main task is to realise if all passed or not. If either of them fails, we stop the execution.

So, I was wondering if there was some "elegant" way to find this and we could simply remove the Seq from the final Future and have something like `Future[Try[Unit]]`.

A code example (which should help understand the problem in a much better way)

```
def f(s: String): Future[Unit] = {
  if(s.isEmpty)
    Future.failed(new Throwable("lalala"))
  else
    Future.successful()
}

val strings: Seq[String] = Seq[String]("abc", "xyz", "lol")

val stringsFuture: Seq[Future[Unit]] = strings.map({ s =>
  f(s)
})

val futureStrings: Future[Seq[Unit]] = Future.sequence(stringsFuture)
val futureStringsTry: Future[Try[Seq[Unit]]] = FutureUtil.toTry(futureStrings)
```

Is there a way where we can convert `futureStringsTry` to a simple `Future[Try[Unit]]`.

A naive solution would be to flatmap `futureStringsTry`, something like this:

```
val finalFuture: Future[Try[Unit]] = futureStringsTry.map({
  case Success(_) => Success()
  case Failure(exception) => Failure(exception)
})
```

But, is there some other way where we can "elegantly" evaluate whether the whole Sequence passed or not?

Comment: You can just discard the output before calling `FutureUtil.toTry` basically with a `map(_ => ())` - you also may use `Future.traverse` inste of `map` + `Future.sequence` - technically speaking I would say that this would be easier with **cats** since it would be `list.traverse_(f).attempt` but: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/4176

Comment: `Future[Try` seems odd because `Future` just like `Try`, but result may be not calculated yet. Maybe you wanna use `Future[Either` to have difference between a bad but valid result and an exception. Also it is not good to create `Throwable`, because `Throwable` is a superclass for Error also,

Comment: *Not an answer*: Future[Unit] feels kind of odd, if we wanted to compare Unit with void, a value which returns nothing in the future, is kind of like a value which just returns nothing, right?